# 3 non-collinear points can represent every point in R2

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

So this is supposed to be a quite easy problem using an orthogonal base but I just can't figure it out :(.
So Let $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ be three non-collinear, different from each other, points}$ Show every point $P\in \mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented with $p = \lambda a + \mu b + \nu c$ with $\lambda + \mu + \nu = 1$

The hint given by my professor was to think about orthogonal bases and orthogonal coordinate system but I just can't wrap my head around it... It would be amazing if you would have some ideas on how to approach this ^^

Comment: The vectors $AB$ and $AC$ form a base of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, given this point $P$, you can write $AP=\mu AB + \nu AC$. Substitute $AB=B-A$, $AC=C-A$, $AP=P-A$ and $\lambda=1-\mu-\nu$ and manipulate.

Comment: Omg thx a lot! This really works :o I have to do some drawing to really understand WHY this works abut it's already amazing to have a working solution ^^

Comment: But why are AB and AC linearly independent? collinear just means that they are on a line through the origin right? this shouldn't work out?

Comment: No. Collinear means that you can pass through the three points with the same line (not necessarily passing through the origin). If $AB$ and $AC$ were linearly dependent ($\exists k\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $AB=kAC$) you would find that the 3 points are collinear. So, $AB$ and $AC$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Oh thx. That makes a lot of sense. The wikipedia article is slightly confusing about this but that makes a lot more sense :) Thx a lot again for the help ^^